# Extending polylines with points from Excel/Access file

Tags: arcmap, line, vertices

I have a `.shp`-file filled with polylines, where some of them are currently being drawn as a straight line from A-B, where in reality they curve a lot along the way.

In the shapefile, I have an `"ID"` that matches with an Access/Excel table where I have the coordinates for all the vertices that need to be added to the lines in order for them to have their correct position.

I need to change the lines from straight lines to lines with a lot of vertices using coordinates from my Acces/Excel-file. CRS is the same for both files, and there are about 15.000 vertices in total.

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1, Advanced license, with Spatial/3D Analyst.

[image: example]

[image: Example of exceldata]

Comment: Do your points share the same CRS with polylines?

Comment: Yes, the coordinate system is the same. All the data should be compatible, just don't know how to combine it.

Comment: @BERA Not really sure how that would work, doesn't that only give the start coordinates and end coordinates? If we take the line ID21 as an example I have 216 vertices I need to move from the Excel file onto the line so it follows the correct path. Forgive me if I'm being stupid, but can XY To Line do that?

Comment: I think you'll need ArcPy to do this and, for that, you'll need to provide a code attempt to get help with your code because we don't provide a code writing service.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks, I was hoping to avoid ArcPy as it's not my strong suit, but will try and give it a go. Appreciate the fast response and help :)

Comment: If you can get from your CSV to points first then the [Points To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm) tool looks like it should get you most if not all the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After PolyGeo's suggestion with Points To Line, I did the following steps:

- New sort field in Accessdata to get the right route (0-1-2-3-4-5).
- Create Point Layer using the Access data
- Then Point To Line with ID and Sort field active
- Lastly did a join from my old shape file with correct attributes on the new layer line layer with correct paths/routes.

Now I have everything as needed!